# Dual power supply circuit

Tags: power-supply, batteries

I want to power a device from a battery and be able to plug it in a power source (PC). Will this circuit work?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvWa7B.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/261179/dual-power-supply-battery-and-5v/

Comment: @VasilKalchev: That is very interesting but why are you telling us this? Do you have a question? Do you have datasheet links to the devices mentioned?

Comment: The question got lost in the `alt` tag of the schematic. I'm asking if it will work. [3.3V LDO voltage regulator](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/389/ld1117-974075.pdf), [P MOSFET, logic level](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/FQP27P06.pdf), [TP4056 Li-ion charger](https://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Prototyping/TP4056.pdf), the batteries are 18650 Li-ion. I don't want to use the diode circuit because half the battery won't get used.

Comment: Whenever you close SW1, you'll be shorting 5V to BAT+ through the body diode of M2.

Comment: What "diode circuit" are you referring to? What is the acceptable Vmin of your device?

Comment: [This is the diode circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/261179/dual-power-supply-battery-and-5v/). My device works on 3.3V regulated. This regulator will work while the battery voltage is above ~3.5V.

Comment: The datasheet you linked to says the dropout voltage is ~1-1.2V for the regulator you selected. You might want to consider a different part.